# Is it bad to underflow then overflow an unsigned variable?

Tags: c, c89, size-t, underflow

Kraaa.

I am a student in a programming school who requires us to write C functions with less than 25 lines of code. So, basically, every line counts. Sometimes, I have the need to shorten assignments like so:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define ARRAY_SIZE  3

int     main(void)
{
    int     nbr_array[ARRAY_SIZE] = { 1, 2, 3 };
    size_t  i;

    i = -1;
    while (++i < ARRAY_SIZE)
        printf("nbr_array[%zu] = %i\n", i, nbr_array[i]);
    return (0);
}
```

The important part of this code is the `size_t` counter named `i`. In order to save up several lines of code, I would like to pre-increment it in the loop's condition. But, insofar as the C standard defines `size_t` as an unsigned type, what I am basically doing here, is underflowing the `i` variable (from 0 to a very big value), then overflowing it once (from that big value to 0).

My question is the following: regardless of the *bad practises* of having to shorten our code, **is it safe to set an `unsigned` (`size_t`) variable to -1 then pre-increment it at each iteration** to browse an array?

Thanks!

Comment: To help with "less than 25 lines", could eliminate `#define ARRAY_SIZE  3`.  Use `int  nbr_array[] = { 1, 2, 3 }; while (++i < sizeof(nbr_array)/sizeof(nbr_array[0])`

Comment: You could also be a bit of a smart aleck with the lines of code issue, and just put everything (but the preprocessing) on one line...

Comment: You could write a C99-compliant program by omitting `return 0;`. That would save one line (and parentheses aren't needed in `return 0;`, saving two characters for extra credit).

Comment: using a `for` loop with a local variable `i` not only would save you lines of code, but improve readability, which, I guess, is the idea behind the restriction of the number of lines. You could then start your `i` with `0` as anyone expects, and as an extra bonus, your whole problem disappears :)

Comment: @JensGustedt The OP commented below that they are only allowed to use `while`. This is a very strange way to learn C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `i = -1;` part of your program is fine.

Converting `-1` to an unsigned integer type is defined in C, and results in a value that, if incremented, results in zero.

This said, you are not gaining any line of code with respect to the idiomatic `for (i=0; i<ARRAY_SIZE; i++) …`.

Your `%zi` format should probably be `%zu`.

Comment: The programming standard in action at my school forbids us to use anything else than `while()` loop statements. Oh, thanks for your comment about the format modifier; I believe `%zi` shall be for `ssize_t`?

Comment: @Diti It would make sense, seeing as `ssize_t` is defined as the signed type corresponding to `size_t`, but you won't find the C standard saying it's okay, as `ssize_t` is a POSIX extension (and I do not have access to POSIX so I can't tell if it suggests `%zi` for printing).

Answer (score 1):

Unsigned arithmetic never "overflows/underflows" (at least in the way the standard talks about the undefined behavior of signed arithmetic overflow). All unsigned arithmetic is actually [*modular arithmetic*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic), and as such is safe (i.e. it won't cause undefined behavior in and of itself).

Answer (score 1):

To be precise, the C standard guarantees two things:

- Any integer conversion to an `unsigned` type is well defined (as if the signed number were represented as 2-complement)
- overflow/underflow of `unsigned` integers is well defined (modular arithmetic with 2^n)

Since `size_t` is an unsigned type, you are not doing anything evil.

Comment: "*2-complement representation*": Neither signed nor unsigned integers are required to be 2's complement.

Comment: 2's complement is a representation for signed values. Any notion of encoding of negative values is irrelevant for an unsigned type. The standard only says that unsigned types are represented in “pure binary representation”.

Comment: What I meant is that the resulting unsigned number is required to be the same that results from reinterpreting the bit pattern of a 2-complement signed number as an unsigned one, truncating it to the correct width. That is the easiest way to think of it for me, the standard uses different wording, but the meaning is the same.

Comment: @cmaster: The reason that casting a signed value to unsigned yields the numbers it does doesn't really have anything to do with the fact that many systems store signed values in two's-complement form, but instead with the fact that (unsigned thing)((unsigned thing)(-x) + (unsigned thing)(x))` should equal zero.